# How to get element references of Virtualize component's children?

Tags: c#, blazor, ui-virtualization

I use Virtualize component like this:

```
<Virtualize Items="Items" Context="row">
   <Row Data="row" @key="row" />
</Virtualize>
```

How do I get references to current `<Row>` components?

I need to explicitly call refresh on them.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could do something like this:

```
<Virtualize Items="Items" Context="row">
    <Row Data="row" @key="row" @ref="references[row.id]" />
</Virtualize>

@code {

    IDictionary<string, ElementReference> references = new Dictionary<string, ElementReference>()
    {
        { "<first row id>", new ElementReference() },
        { "<second row id>", new ElementReference() },
        { "<third row id>", new ElementReference() },
        
        ...      
    };

}
```